# How to append a string in bash only when the variable is defined and not null?

Tags: bash

I want to obtain the following behaviour in `bash` and I have the impression that this is possible in one line but I don't know the exact syntax (and was not able to find it in the doc).

```
FOO=somename
BAR=123
```

If BAR is not defined or empty the final result should be just `somename`.
If BAR has a value the final result should be `somename-123`

Current example is adding a dash even when BAR is not defined and that's not what I want.

echo "${FOO}-${BAR}"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter:+word}
          Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or  unset,  nothing  is
          substituted, otherwise the expansion of word is substituted.
```

Example:

```
foo="somename"
bar="123"
echo "${foo}${bar:+-$bar}"
```

This prints `somename-123`. If you set `bar=""`, it prints `somename`.

Answer (score 0):

Some concrete examples for those trying to manage common system paths:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_PRELOAD=${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/libiomp5.so${LD_PRELOAD:+:${LD_PRELOAD}}
```