# How to understand "${PATH:+:${PATH}}" in bash?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I am seeing the following code in a bash script:

```bash
export PATH=/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-python38/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

I do not understand the last part, where `${PATH:+:${PATH}}` is manipulated.

Comment: See also: [StackExchange: What does ${PATH:+:${PATH}} mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267506/310674) and [What is the different between PATH=:$PATH and PATH="$PATH:" and other export lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49193620/7939871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's to append `:` and `$PATH`, but only if `$PATH` is non-empty; otherwise, nothing gets added.

The syntax for the [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) is `${parameter:+word}`, and it stands for

> If *`parameter`* is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of *`word`* is substituted.

In your example, *`word`* is `:$PATH`.

There is a subtlety around `${parameter:+word}` vs. `${parameter+word}`, where the former substitutes nothing if *`parameter`* is unset *or null*, and the latter substitutes nothing only if *`parameter`* is unset (but could be empty).