# Setting build version in YAML Azure Pipeline, with bash - conditional branch name

Tags: bash, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to set the Build Name to be "version-branchname", for example "345-branch" only when a branch is present (i.e. when not building from main).

To do this, i'm trying the following:

```
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019
steps:
- bash: |
    echo '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'$(Build.BuildNumber)$($(Build.SourceBranchName):+-$(Build.SourceBranchName))
```

Based on a previous answer on how to do this in bash:
[How to append a string in bash only when the variable is defined and not null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771781/how-to-append-a-string-in-bash-only-when-the-variable-is-defined-and-not-null)

However, this outputs the following (azure-pipelines is the branch name):

> line 1: azure-pipelines:+-azure-pipelines: command not found

I've tried a few different combos of this - most of the time ending up with the build stopping, as the output BuildNumber ends up being non-compliant with the requirements of Azure Pipelines.

Is there a better way to do this, or am i missing something obvious?

Here's more clarity on what i'm trying to achieve:

- If this is a build of the "main" branch, the version number would
  simply be a number.
- If this is a build of a branch other than "main",
  the version number and branch name combine to create the build
  number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after tinkering, i changed my approach to set branch name if the sourcebranchname length was greater than 0, which is not perfect, but allows me control to build what i need.

Here's an example:

```
name: $(Rev:r)

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- bash: echo '##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]'$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)
  condition: ${{ gt(length(variables['Build.SourceBranchName']),0) }}
  displayName: 'Set Build Version to include branch, if branch build'
```